# Image processing using OpenCV on OpenGL graphics

Tags: opencv, c++11, opengl, cluster-analysis

As title says, I want to know if there is a way to process graphics using OpenCV created by OpenGL?
I am displaying thousands of points in real-time using OpenGL. Now I want to create clusters for those points and later point-tracking.
I have found [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/opengl_interop.html) but couldn't understand it well.
Apart from that on [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/266752/opengl-vs-opencv-for-beginner/266758) page a guy mentioned "OpenCV generally operates on real image data, and wouldn't operate on graphics generated by OpenGL."
Is it true?
Below is one of the screenshot of real-time output.
[image]

Comment: opencv can work on any images. But it might be easier to not work on images (from where you would have to extract the rendered points again - leading to errors) but to fetch the projected points from vertex buffers or sth. directly from openGL. Can you upload a sample image?

Comment: @Micka Thank you very much for reply.
I edited the question with a sample picture.

Comment: can you explain or manipulate the image to show your desired result from OpenCV output?

Comment: I think I can.
I am going to use Kalman Filter for object-tracking and I have made some research for that.
If I can manage to interpolate those points in OpenCV, I can make cluster which is the most important for object-tracking.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve with those images. You'll have to explain much more detailed. Is each of the "lines" in your image one track of a single object? Sorry, nothing clear yet. draw some information to that image to explain. Explain what those circles mean, and so on. Draw in your image WHAT exactly you want to cluster. The nice thing in computer vision is that you typically have images to support your explanations, so use it :)

Comment: I asked the question in detail here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721222/data-clustering-in-c-using-opengl) 
The pic is a screenshot while I doing some static test. The dot in the middle is my sensor, each circle around it is just for the distance(in meter) form the sensor.
Now if you see the pic carefully, you'll find a green spot(approximately at 3.9 m from the middle point) in it. That's because of high reflective material. So for now I want to make clusters of only those green points. But I don't know how to pass those points in OpenCV and how to make a cluster?

Comment: you can detect those points by simple color detection (just check each pixel whether it is the desired color or by using cv::inRange function). If you know the number of clusters you can use k-means. No idea about solutions without known cluster number. That doesn't sound like a computer vision (only) problem, so openCV might not be the right tool to cluster the detected points.

Comment: I don't know the number of cluster(s) and can never be known in this case. So I might will use DBSCAN where I don't need to specify number of clusters.  
I want to use OpenCV because I think it'd be bit easy for clustering & object-tracking.

Comment: Don't pick an algorithm because you like the parameters. Choose it because it solves the right problem, because they don't do the same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use glReadPixels to copy the rendered result to the main memory. Then you can create a cv::Mat out of the buffer.